# vue.js keep-alive and event rendering

Tags: vue.js, keep-alive

I have 1 master component and 2 childs.
In the master i do :

```
  <keep-alive>
    <component :is="getChild" @onrender="childRender" />
  </keep-alive>
```

So I switch from child 1 to child 2 and keep state of each.

- getChild switch child component (buttons... not the problem here).
- onrender is emit when child load
- childRender just write a console.log.

**Problem** : when we use keep-alive, the child component is not re-render and when i use onCreated or onMounted or onUpdated... nothing append and it's normal. So how catch a "render" event with keep-alive ?

I know i can use a bus or a store like Vuex to keep state... but i don't want it if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In 2.2.0+ and above, activated and deactivated will fire for all nested components inside a  tree.

Use activated lifecycle hook.

```
export default {
  activated() {
    this.$emit("activated");
  }
}
```

Vue.js Documentation link: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive

Live demo, where you can play with `<keep-alive>`: https://codepen.io/3vilArthas/pen/BeZgbE

Comment: This is excellent! It was very easy to not discover this lifecycle, as the related document page does not make note of it here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#keep-alive-with-Dynamic-Components Thank you!